# Corrupt registry: Duplicate entries for /etc/default/grub

Tags: 14.04, grub2

Whenever I try to install any package from apt-get, I am getting this error:

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.7) ...
ucfr: Corrupt registry: Duplicate entries for /etc/default/grub
grub-pc      /etc/default/grub
grub-pc      /etc/default/grub
grub-pc      /etc/default/grub
grub-pc      /etc/default/grub
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4

Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I checked from /etc/default/grub file and did not find any duplicate entries. I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the full content of your `/etc/default/grub` file? Leave me a comment after you updated your post. Thanks!

Comment: Check your `/var/lib/ucf/registry` file I had the same issue and the `/etc/default/grub` was listed twice.